# SSRS - 'measures' field working in Dataset, but won't appear in report

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, dataset, report, mdx

I have a dataset that fetches data from SSAS cube using MDX query, I executed and confirmed that the MDX query retrieves measure values in SSMS Query Designer. However, when I drag the fields onto a Table in SSRS report, only the dimension values appear but not the measure (it shows up empty).

I believe this is an issue specific to Visual Studio 2017, the SSRS report displays the measure values fine when run in Visual Studio 2015.

I have only started encountering this issue in the last two days. Before that the report was displaying values correctly in Visual Studio 2017.

Please provide steps to fix this issue.

Comment: It seems to be the issue with corrupted VS 2017. I had to uninstall and re-install the software, which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild rdl file in VS 2017 - the issue is probably because of different default  xml schema versions.